# How to count max amplitude of sound in android?

Tags: android, audio, pitch-tracking, sound-recognition

I am here searching for a functionality of counting max amplitude sound of punching.
i used android speech recognition API in my demo app but it is counting all sound(noise) and count are running like bullet speed. 
I want count only punch impacting on punch bag sound and don't want to miss any punch, with this count won't be change on music, talking and sneezing sound.

Comment: Pitch and amplitude are two different things.

Comment: Ohh.. Very sorry Michael. I am applying my functionality according to amplitude of sound. Now Can you help me. please.